# angular2 show view and data and same time

Tags: angular

I am using angular2 rc6.  I notice that my view shows first then data.

How can I make sure all data is loaded then show my data with the view?

For example with a input text box on edit the box shows then e.g. 1 second later then value.  I have been doing my network calls in ngOnInit()

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div *ngIf="data">
  {{data}}
</div>
```

If you use the router you can also use resolve and guards.

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#guards

Answer (score 0):

You can get data in route resolve.

Angular2 Route Resolve: **pre-fetching component data**

Please check, how to use angular2 route resolve: [Click here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#resolve-guard)